# Google play one time product purchase - Real-time developer notifications

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to handle refunds for google play one-time purchase products. I am not able to get a real time notification when I refund the item from the play store.

Do refunds send real-time developer notifications, what kind?  ONE_TIME_PRODUCT_CANCELED?
Is it possible to test or get notifications for a google play refund in test/sandbox environment?

Comment: I believe Google Play has a Closed Testing option.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to know if are there any  real-time developer notifications sent, when a refund is processed by Google Play Billing.

Comment: It looks like play store does not send notifications for refunded products. A server side check can be made at the google play developer api to get a list of voided purchases which contains the canceled/refunded/charged-back packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update November 2023: Android now send [VoidedPurchaseNotifications](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/rtdn-reference#voided-purchase)

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't real time developer notification for refunds. You need to poll data from this api and perform refunds that way on your side.

[VoidedPurchases api](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.voidedpurchases#VoidedPurchase)